# Matching values in two diffent sheets to fetch a third [google-apps-script]

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to match names from one sheet with names from a a reference data sheet to pull the corresponding emails to the new sheet.  I have tried the following code with no success.  I manage a ski club with members that have the same last names, and VLOOKUP stops at the first match.  I need to confirm both the first and last name in order to fetch the appropriate email.

[Mail sift sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S8Fw2zMjkI7TzKLEh2zvYdlOd-coKI2-8L6OLrnfOnE/edit?usp=sharing)

The code I have tried is as follows;

```
  function getEmail() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
     var sheetRoster = ss.getSheets()[0];
     var sheetTrip = ss.getSheets()[1];
     var startRow = 2;
     var tripData = sheetTrip.getRange(startRow, 2, sheetTrip.getLastRow());
     var rosterData = sheetRoster.getRange(startRow,2,sheetRoster.getLastRow());

     for (var i = 0; i < rosterData.length; i++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < tripData.length; k++) {
        if((tripData[k][1] == rosterData[i][1])&&(tripData[k][0] == rosterData[i][0])){
          tripData[k][2] = (rosterData[i][2]);
        }
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines of code to get data, are missing the `getValues()` method. Change:

```
var tripData = sheetTrip.getRange(startRow, 2, sheetTrip.getLastRow());
var rosterData = sheetRoster.getRange(startRow,2,sheetRoster.getLastRow());
```

TO:

```
var tripData = sheetTrip.getRange(startRow, 1, sheetTrip.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
var rosterData = sheetRoster.getRange(startRow,1,sheetRoster.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
```

Also note, that you need 4 parameters.  You need both columns of data, so you need a fourth parameter that is the number 2, to get 2 columns of data.  And start in column 1.  So the second parameter needs to be changed to 1.

To see the results, use a `Logger.log('tripData: ' + tripData);` statement, run the code, and then in the VIEW menu, choose LOGS.

Also, subtract 1 from the row length to avoid getting blank value in the array at the end, since you are starting in row 2.

Actually, you need to get all 3 columns from the roster, because you need to retrieve the email.  And loop through the trip data in the outer loop.  Here is code that is looking up the email and adding it.  Note that it's case sensitive, so it didn't match the first names starting will lower case letters.

```
function getEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetRoster = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetTrip = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var startRow = 2;
  var tripData = sheetTrip.getRange(startRow, 1, sheetTrip.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
  var rosterData = sheetRoster.getRange(startRow,1,sheetRoster.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();//Get Two columns of data for first and last name
  var firstName, lastName;

  Logger.log('rosterData: ' + rosterData);

  for (var i = 0; i < tripData.length; i++) {
    firstName = tripData[i][0];
    lastName = tripData[i][1];

    Logger.log(firstName + " " + lastName);

    for (var k = 0; k < rosterData.length; k++) {
      if ((firstName == rosterData[k][0]) && (lastName == rosterData[k][1])) {     
        sheetTrip.getRange(k+2, 3).setValue(rosterData[i][2])
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: This works at fetching the email addresses, but the emails to not line up with the appropriate name.

Comment: Change `i` to `k` in `sheetTrip.getRange(k+2, 3).setValue(rosterData[i][2])`.  Are they always off by the same number of rows in the same direction?

Comment: The change was the first thing I checked as well.  They are all different values away from the target names.  I'll try making the switch and posting an update.  Thanks.

Comment: It is working perfectly now.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and marking answer as correct.